# ES6 return a new keypair values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to return a new object with new keypair and its values

```
let input= {
"Bhang Seeds": 120,
"CRON": 300,
"F1 Hybrid": 180,
}
```

expected output

```
[
{
variety: 'Bhang Seeds',
Quantity:180
},
variety: 'CRON',
Quantity:300
},
{
variety: 'F1 Hybrid',
Quantity:180
}
]
```

I have tried below and separated keys and values. Now how can I return this with new keypair values?

```
        const varietyKey = Object.keys(response).map(v => v);
        console.log(varietyKey);
        const varietyValue: any = Object.values(response).map(v => v);
        console.log(variety);
```

Comment: your input object is invalid - also, why is bhang seeds 180 on the output, and what happened to the hybrids on output? also `const varietyValue: any` is not ecmascript

Comment: your edit still doesn't explain why the value of bhang seeds changes to the value of f1 hybrid, and f1 hybrid disappears from the output

Comment: I have a response with key name as seed and its value, I want to make that response as mentioned in the expected output.

Comment: there's no description for the logic in the value changes and the exclusion from the output

Comment: yet, still, bhang seeds value changes ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.key` to get the keys. Use that to iterate over the object and build the new desired output.

```js
var input = {
  'Bhang Seeds': 120,
  'CRON': 300,
  'F1 Hybrid': 180,
  'F1 Hybrids': 130,
  'F2-Hybrids': 100
}

const out = Object.keys(input).map(k => ({
 variety: k,
 Quantity: input[k] 
}))

console.log(out)
```

Comment: that's what I suggested, but the output doesn't match OP's bizarre *expected output*

Comment: @JaromandaX, I assumed the expected output is trimming the ignoring the rest.

Comment: @teja - not according to your question

Comment: @AdamAzad - the `q` in quantity is needs to be `Q` - and bhang seeds quantity needs to be 180, not 120 (with no explanation in the question)

Comment: @JaromandaX, fair enough, if OP wants it. I find it bizarre that one key is lowercase and the other is title case.

Comment: @AdamAzad - lazy question :p

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try object.entries like so:

```js
const newArr = Object.entries(yourObj).map(([key, value]) => ({variety: key, quantity:value}))
```